# Rebind Excel f9/shift f9/ctrl f9 keys to original functions

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a spreadsheet where I've rebound the calculation keys in workbook_open using onkey:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.OnKey "{F9}", "HandleF9"
 Application.OnKey "^{F9}", "HandleCtrlF9"
 Application.OnKey "+{F9}", "HandleShiftF9"
 End Sub
```

This works fine. However, obviously it rebounds the calculation keys for all the spreadsheets open in that instance of excel.  The effect remains even once the spreadsheet that does the rebounding is closed.

I wanted to get around this behaviour by having something in workbook_close that undoes the keybininding. This would mean that once the spreadsheet is closed, the f9 functionality returns to normal. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the second (Optional) parameter to return to normal functionality [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx).

> Procedure (Optional) A string indicating the name of the procedure to be run. If Procedure is "" (empty text), nothing happens when Key is pressed. This form of OnKey changes the normal result of keystrokes in Microsoft Excel. If Procedure is omitted, Key reverts to its normal result in Microsoft Excel, and any special key assignments made with previous OnKey methods are cleared.

```
   Application.OnKey "{F9}"
   Application.OnKey "^{F9}"
   Application.OnKey "+{F9}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just omit the procedure argument

```
Application.OnKey "{F9}"
```